# Java Cloning and downcasting

Tags: java, clone, downcast

Below is my sample code:

```
class One implements Cloneable {
    @Override
    public One clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        One obj = (One) super.clone();
        return obj;
    }
}

public class Two extends One {
    @Override
    public Two clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Two obj1 = (Two) super.clone(); // Line 12
        return obj1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean num = true;
        try {
            if ((new Two().clone()) instanceof One) {
                num = false;
            }
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

It prints false.

Can someone explain what is happening in Line 12?
Why this downcast does not throw exception?

Comment: Why should it throw?

Comment: Why doesn't it throw? Because *magic*. Magic as black as a moonless night. `clone()` does weird, JVM-level things.

Answer (score 0):

Because of line 4. It call `Object.clone()`. That method do MAGIC. It create new instance with the same runtime type as existing instnce.